# str.format a list by joining its values

Tags: python

Say I have a dictionary:

```
data = {
"user" : {
   "properties" : ["i1", "i2"]
}
}
```

And the following string:

```
txt = "The user has properties {user[properties]}"
```

I want to have:

```
txt.format(**data)
```

to equal:

```
The user has properties i1, i2
```

I believe to achieve this, I could subclass the formatter used by str.format but I am unfortunately unsure how to proceed. I rarely subclass standard Python classes. Note that writing `{user[properties][0]}, {user[properties][1]}` is not an ideal option for me here. I don't know how many items are in the list so I would need to do a regex to identify matches, then find the relevant value in `data` and replace the matched text with `{user[properties][0]}, {user[properties][1]}`. `str.format` takes care of all the indexing from the string's value so it is very practical.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the items in `data["user"]["properties"]`

```
txt = "The user has properties {properties}"
txt.format(properties = ", ".join(data["user"]["properties"]))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/SereneUnsightlyMouse)

Comment: The issue is my string is predefined, it's a text block template that is then filled in with the content. Similarly, I need to use a dictionary as input to str.format(). So, I can't simply replace what I wrote with the "properties" key. I've done this for now using regex, basically implementing this solution, but I was wondering if there was something better I could do.

Comment: @Konrad, I dont think you will find a better solution thatn to replace your to be formatted string with a proper sintax

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the jinja2 package for all of my formatting needs. It's extremely powerful and I really recommend it!